# Source command looping a list of files

Tags: perl, loops

I have exhausted my brain trying to do something that might be easy for someone with a little more experience in programming Perl than I do.

I have the code below.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @lines = do {
  open my $in_fh, '<', 'input.txt' or die qq{Unable to open "input.txt" for input: $!};
  <$in_fh>;
};
chomp @lines;
my $re = join '|', @lines;

my @files = grep /^(?:$re)/, glob '*.bam';
$_ = "INPUT=$_" for @files;


foreach my $file (@files) {
    foreach my $line (@lines) {
        if ($file =~ m/$line/) {
            my $command = "picard MergeSamFiles $file OUTPUT=$line" . "-tmp-herc2.bam MERGE_SEQUENCE_DICTIONARIES=TRUE CREATE_INDEX=TRUE";  
            system($command);
            my $command2 = "picard MarkDuplicates $line OUTPUT=$line-herc2.bam METRICS_FILE=tmp REMOVE_DUPLICATES=TRUE CREATE_INDEX=TRUE";
            system($command2);
                unlink "$line-tmp-herc2.bam";
                unlink "$line-tmp-herc2.bai";
                unlink "tmp";
        }
    }
}
```

Inside the input.txt I have the sample names that will verify if the sample is in the directory. For this example I just used two samples.

```
HG00096
HG00117
```

So, with the code above, I'm getting something like this.

```
picard MergeSamFiles INPUT=HG00096.mapped.ILLUMINA.bwa.GBR.exome.20120522.bam_herc2_data.bam OUTPUT=HG00096-tmp-herc2.bam MERGE_SEQUENCE_DICTIONARIES=TRUE CREATE_INDEX=TRUE
picard MarkDuplicates HG00096 OUTPUT=HG00096-herc2.bam METRICS_FILE=tmp REMOVE_DUPLICATES=TRUE CREATE_INDEX=TRUE
picard MergeSamFiles INPUT=HG00096.mapped.ILLUMINA.bwa.GBR.low_coverage.20101123.bam_herc2_phase1.bam OUTPUT=HG00096-tmp-herc2.bam MERGE_SEQUENCE_DICTIONARIES=TRUE CREATE_INDEX=TRUE
picard MarkDuplicates HG00096 OUTPUT=HG00096-herc2.bam METRICS_FILE=tmp REMOVE_DUPLICATES=TRUE CREATE_INDEX=TRUE
picard MergeSamFiles INPUT=HG00096.mapped.ILLUMINA.bwa.GBR.low_coverage.20120522.bam_herc2_data.bam OUTPUT=HG00096-tmp-herc2.bam MERGE_SEQUENCE_DICTIONARIES=TRUE CREATE_INDEX=TRUE
picard MarkDuplicates HG00096 OUTPUT=HG00096-herc2.bam METRICS_FILE=tmp REMOVE_DUPLICATES=TRUE CREATE_INDEX=TRUE
picard MergeSamFiles INPUT=HG00096.mapped.illumina.mosaik.GBR.exome.20110411.bam_herc2_phase1.bam OUTPUT=HG00096-tmp-herc2.bam MERGE_SEQUENCE_DICTIONARIES=TRUE CREATE_INDEX=TRUE
picard MarkDuplicates HG00096 OUTPUT=HG00096-herc2.bam METRICS_FILE=tmp REMOVE_DUPLICATES=TRUE CREATE_INDEX=TRUE
picard MergeSamFiles INPUT=HG00117.mapped.ILLUMINA.bwa.GBR.exome.20120522.bam_herc2_data.bam OUTPUT=HG00117-tmp-herc2.bam MERGE_SEQUENCE_DICTIONARIES=TRUE CREATE_INDEX=TRUE
picard MarkDuplicates HG00117 OUTPUT=HG00117-herc2.bam METRICS_FILE=tmp REMOVE_DUPLICATES=TRUE CREATE_INDEX=TRUE
picard MergeSamFiles INPUT=HG00117.mapped.ILLUMINA.bwa.GBR.low_coverage.20101123.bam_herc2_phase1.bam OUTPUT=HG00117-tmp-herc2.bam MERGE_SEQUENCE_DICTIONARIES=TRUE CREATE_INDEX=TRUE
picard MarkDuplicates HG00117 OUTPUT=HG00117-herc2.bam METRICS_FILE=tmp REMOVE_DUPLICATES=TRUE CREATE_INDEX=TRUE
picard MergeSamFiles INPUT=HG00117.mapped.ILLUMINA.bwa.GBR.low_coverage.20120522.bam_herc2_data.bam OUTPUT=HG00117-tmp-herc2.bam MERGE_SEQUENCE_DICTIONARIES=TRUE CREATE_INDEX=TRUE
picard MarkDuplicates HG00117 OUTPUT=HG00117-herc2.bam METRICS_FILE=tmp REMOVE_DUPLICATES=TRUE CREATE_INDEX=TRUE
picard MergeSamFiles INPUT=HG00117.mapped.illumina.mosaik.GBR.exome.20110411.bam_herc2_phase1.bam OUTPUT=HG00117-tmp-herc2.bam MERGE_SEQUENCE_DICTIONARIES=TRUE CREATE_INDEX=TRUE
picard MarkDuplicates HG00117 OUTPUT=HG00117-herc2.bam METRICS_FILE=tmp REMOVE_DUPLICATES=TRUE CREATE_INDEX=TRUE
```

When I actually wanted something like this.

```
picard MergeSamFiles INPUT=HG00096.mapped.ILLUMINA.bwa.GBR.exome.20120522.bam_herc2_data.bam INPUT=HG00096.mapped.ILLUMINA.bwa.GBR.low_coverage.20101123.bam_herc2_phase1.bam INPUT=HG00096.mapped.ILLUMINA.bwa.GBR.low_coverage.20120522.bam_herc2_data.bam INPUT=HG00096.mapped.illumina.mosaik.GBR.exome.20110411.bam_herc2_phase1.bam   OUTPUT=HG00096-tmp-herc2.bam MERGE_SEQUENCE_DICTIONARIES=TRUE CREATE_INDEX=TRUE
picard MarkDuplicates HG00096-tmp-herc2.bam OUTPUT=HG00096-herc2.bam METRICS_FILE=tmp REMOVE_DUPLICATES=TRUE CREATE_INDEX=TRUE

picard MergeSamFiles INPUT=HG00117.mapped.ILLUMINA.bwa.GBR.exome.20120522.bam_herc2_data.bam INPUT=HG00117.mapped.ILLUMINA.bwa.GBR.low_coverage.20101123.bam_herc2_phase1.bam INPUT=HG00117.mapped.ILLUMINA.bwa.GBR.low_coverage.20120522.bam_herc2_data.bam INPUT=HG00117.mapped.illumina.mosaik.GBR.exome.20110411.bam_herc2_phase1.bam OUTPUT=HG00117-tmp-herc2.bam MERGE_SEQUENCE_DICTIONARIES=TRUE CREATE_INDEX=TRUE
picard MarkDuplicates HG00117-tmp-herc2.bam OUTPUT=HG00117-herc2.bam METRICS_FILE=tmp REMOVE_DUPLICATES=TRUE CREATE_INDEX=TRUE
```

So the `INPUT` data should be together in order to the system `command` merge de files e generate the `OUTPUT` for the next source `command2`.

I know I'm messing around with the foreach loop but I tried to figure out how to correctly iterate this and I got stuck.

Hope you can help me with this issue.

Comment: It'd be nice to know what the input is.

Comment: INPUT is there...
The @files grab the list of files INPUT=HG00096.mapped.ILLUMINA.bwa.GBR.exome.20120522.bam_herc2_data.bam INPUT=HG00096.mapped.ILLUMINA.bwa.GBR.low_coverage.20101123.bam_herc2_phase1.bam INPUT=HG00096.mapped.ILLUMINA.bwa.GBR.low_coverage.20120522.bam_herc2_data.bam INPUT=HG00096.mapped.illumina.mosaik.GBR.exome.20110411.bam_herc2_phase1.bam  

And so on for all files .bam inside the folder.

Comment: What is in input.txt?

Comment: @guidebortoli: Add this in your question from comment.

Answer (score 0):

In the first command, you add a suffix to the OUTPUT file:

```
my $command = "picard MergeSamFiles $file OUTPUT=$line" . "-tmp-herc2.bam MERGE_SEQUENCE_DICTIONARIES=TRUE CREATE_INDEX=TRUE";  
#                                               here ___^_______________^
```

Just do the same for the second command:

```
my $command2 = "picard MarkDuplicates ${line}-tmp-herc2.bam OUTPUT=$line-herc2.bam METRICS_FILE=tmp REMOVE_DUPLICATES=TRUE CREATE_INDEX=TRUE";
#                                    here ___^____________^
```

Comment: Yeah, I originally have this in my code. I just forgot to fix it. Thanks!!

Comment: @guidebortoli: So you have not anymore a problem? Or is it something else?

Comment: my problem is not solved yet. If you look to my foreach looping you'll see I'm getting something that it's not what I want :(
With my code, picard command is applied foreach sample as you can see in the third box, but what I want is in the fourth box, with samples grouped by name... HG00096 and HG00117 for this example above....